# Should "demande de stage" be hand-written or typed?

Tags: société, travail, culture

I want to submit a "demande de stage" in person.

Please, in French culture, should it be hand-written or typed?

Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about customs, not the French language.

Comment: This depends on the industry. If you specify which industry you're applying in, you could ask on [workplace.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

À moins que la candidature se fasse par courriel, la lettre de motivation doit être manuscrite, le Curriculum Vitae est typographié.

Unless it is by e-mail Curriculum Vitae has to be typed, for easy reading, but motivation letter is hand-written to expose clearly your personnality (pay attention to it, it is often a important piece when candidates have similar C.V.).

---

If your writing script is not easy to read, you can type your motivation letter and hand-write the last paragraph.

Comment: Handwritten motivation letters are thankfully becoming less common. I think they'd be considered quaint in my industry, but I'm a developer; there are certainly many recruiters who still expect handwritten motivation letters.

Comment: @Gilles On entre dans le cas de candidature par courriel. Si l'offre demande un courrier, il est préférable de soigner (écriture, orthographe, syntaxe, ....) sa lettre de motivation, car beaucoup d'entreprises sont obligées de payer des formations  de français à nombre de diplômés, tant pour la rédaction de rapports que pour la qualité des contacts commerciaux. Problèmes que l'on rencontre beaucoup moins dans la sphère juridique.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are clearly asked otherwise, you should type both your curriculum vitae and motivation letter.